# How do you activate Office 365 "for the rest of the household"?

Tags: office365

A single Office 365 subscription [apparently](http://blogs.office.com/b/office-news/archive/2012/09/17/the-new-office-365-subscriptions-for-consumers-and-small-businesses.aspx) "covers the entire household": "You can each sign-in with your individual Microsoft accounts using your settings and accessing your documents, but you still need just one subscription".

I bought it with my account, hence I guess there should be some way to tell it which other accounts are part of my household, so that they can download it. However, I haven't found anything like that in the web interface.
So, how do I install the copies for the rest of the family?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the following link and look for the section called "Ability to use Office on up to 5 PCs or Macs shared among all users in the home".

[Install Office 365 Home Premium on a family member's computer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/support/install-office-365-home-premium-on-a-family-member-s-computer-HA103478662.aspx)

The Relevant Sections:

1. > On the computer where you want to install Office, go to Office.com and **sign in with your Microsoft Account**.
2. > Now, anyone who uses this computer will have a full copy of Office.
   >   All they need to do is open an Office program and **sign in with their
   >   Microsoft Account**.

Comment: Ok, I misread that article. The relevant part is: _"Ability to use Office on up to 5 PCs or Macs shared among all users in the home"_.

Comment: Edited the answer to include the section.

Comment: I've also added some bits which were the focus of my confusion.